# Error in Eigen library examples on building my project

Tags: eigen, eigen3

The errors i get are from doc in libraries

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "eigen-.4.0\\doc\\snippets\\MatrixBase_diagonal.o" "..\\..\\eigen-3.4.0\\doc\\snippets\\MatrixBase_diagonal.cpp" 
..\..\eigen-3.4.0\doc\snippets\MatrixBase_diagonal.cpp:1:1: error: 'Matrix3i' does not name a type
 Matrix3i m = Matrix3i::Random();
 ^~~~~~~~
..\..\eigen-3.4.0\doc\snippets\MatrixBase_diagonal.cpp:2:1: error: 'cout' does not name a type
 cout << "Here is the matrix m:" << endl << m << endl;
 ^~~~
..\..\eigen-3.4.0\doc\snippets\MatrixBase_diagonal.cpp:3:1: error: 'cout' does not name a type
 cout << "Here are the coefficients on the main diagonal of m:" << endl
 ^~~~
```

I downloaded Eigen library 3.4.0, currently using eclipse IDE on windows.
Linked the library to my project
Prosperities -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Source Location -> Added Eigen folder path
Prosperities -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes -> Added Eigen folder path.

Tried to compile this simple program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
int main()
{
 MatrixXd m(2,2);
  m(0,0) = 3;
  m(1,0) = 2.5;
  m(0,1) = -1;
  m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
  cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

It would be great help if somebody could point out what I wasn't doing right

Comment: I guess, Eclipse thinks that anything you add to "Source Location" needs to be built (are you using "Managed Build"?). But the code snippets in doc/snippets will not compile on their own. You actually don't need to compile any Eigen file on its own to use Eigen, so perhaps try to remove the Eigen folder from your "Source Location".